# How to access variable defined in constructor from another file in python

Tags: python

I have a python file `file1` which has below code

```
Class myClass():

   def __init__(self):
      self._variable1 = 2
```

Now how can I access variable1 from another python file

```
 from file1 import myClass

    class = myClass()
    class._variable1 ??
```

how can I access these variables.?

Comment: Uh, yes, like that. Except you can't use "class" as an identifier.

Comment: Make sure you get the indentation right. Why are the lines not aligned in file2?

Comment: Sorry not mentioning but the code has variable like `self._variable1`. What does `_variable` means. I tried it with `class._variable1` but intellisense doesnt show it.

Comment: That is a completely different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all done fine, except the name `class` for variable

try it

```
from file1 import myClass

    cl = myClass()
    cl.variable1
```

newer user python keywords as variable name, list of it you may look

```
import keyword
keyword.kwlist
```

more details [lexical_analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)